# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when selecting dropdown options from array in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, use-effect

I have an array called users in useEffect function and I am trying to render it in select option using map function

```
let dropdown= React.createRef();

useEffect(() => {
    setstate({
      users: ['test user', 'lokesh'],
      username: 'test user'
    })
});
```

and I have a form where I want to render it in dropdown

```
<form onSubmit={onsubmit}>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <select ref={dropdown}
        required
        className="form-control"
        value={state.username}
        onChange={onChangeUsername}
      >
        {state.users.map(user => {
          return (
            <option
              key={user}
              value={user}>
              {user}
            </option>
          )
        })}
      </select>
</div>
<form>
```

the page loads but throws error when i click other input-texts

Comment: you are trying to mix class component with functional component. setState is used in class component and you are trying to use the same in functional component. In order to achieve it, you need to use `useState` hook.

Comment: The closing form tag </form> is not there. Is the error because of that?

Comment: @Akhil Aravind, I dont think so. He is using class component here. May be has written a useState statement like below.
const [state, setstate] = useState({
    users: [],
    username: ''
  })

Comment: i have used 'state' as my hook name like const [state, setstate] = useState(...)

Comment: @GangadharGandi class components dont have `useEffect` hook, hooks are only for functional component.

Comment: Please paste the whole form code.

Comment: I think my issue arised because i have setState inside useEffect. but how do I set componentDidMount kind of property in functional component

Answer (score 1):

I have done the stackblitz example here, hope this is the solution you needed. Sorry but I don't know how to create a fiddle here. The way you use `useEffect` here is wrong. And in function component, its not `createRef`, its `useRef` for reference.

[Check the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lpbq9h)

```
useEffect(() => {
setstate({
  users: ['test user', 'lokesh'],
  username: 'test user'
})
},[]);
```

Comment: @LokeshBajracharya i have added changes, so you can view the username change  instantly. hope this helped.

Comment: https://react-nyb4ng.stackblitz.io please could you check this error

Comment: @LokeshBajracharya noting is there, please share the editor link

Comment: Hi, I got my issue. I was not using arrow function to set the value in onChange property. I had setState like setState=({username: e.target.value}). but I dont get it why. could you explain